# How to use the IN operator in a WHERE clause with azure-mobile-apps-js-client

Tags: sql, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to write a cordova mobile app query that incorporates something like the SQL **IN** or the **OR** operator in a where clause.

According to the query string documentation that I could find (https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) and what I'm seeing in the debugger, the below code should be converting to an **AND** operator:

```
var arr = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
var query = new WindowsAzure.Query('tableNm').where({circleNm: arr});
```

The resulting where, though **not desired**, should be interpreted as:

```
circleNm=test1 and circleNm=test2 and circleNm=test3
```

How do I get something equivalent to the following instead?

```
circleNm IN ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I expect this library can't do "IN" -- remember that "IN" is functionally the same to a join.

Comment: Can it do an "OR"?

Comment: yes it is the same as the IN.  Here is a code example: https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/b5e3dec946e1f9d82910adfeafdae518  -- see how it works now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IN predicate can be constructed by using the following syntax:

```
query.where(function (items) {
    return this.value in items;
}, ['1', '2', '3'])
```

Here, `this.value` represents the `value` column from the table being queried.